# How do I load data into Spark standalone cluster from the driver program, that does not fit in the driver memory?

Tags: apache-spark

In my scenario I have a Spark is running in stand alone mode, with many worker nodes with virtually unlimited RAM.

In my scenario I load the data in the driver program (Apache Zeppelin), then create RDD and DataFrame from it. The size of the data exceeds the RAM of the driver program.

How can I load that data (from the driver process) and create DataFrame from it?

An example would be extremely helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't actually get your question. "Unlimited RAM" and "data exceeds the RAM" are contradictory concepts for me. Please read on how to ask questions on SO and review your question ! I'm voting to close it for now as unclear.

Comment: The "unlimited" RAM is on the workers, the limited RAM is on the driver program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal usage for driver are

- tell the executor what to do
- collect/share the result

load data to driver and create RDD/DataFrame/Dataset should be only used in experiment case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the only choice is to tell the worker to load the data themselves. In case Spark doesn't support your Input format, you will have to extend the RDD class and implement the compute function.

Answer (score 0):

I ambit really sure why you have to load the data into the driver. It doesn't really makes sense in the distributed world. I suggest you save/move your data into your cluster in a distributed (hdfs) mode and load it from there. If your data is not already there, there are many open source solutions that can transport it. Moreover, you can save it to any other supported file system such as s3.